# Trying to use Python to create a While statement for a Travel Program

Tags: python, while-loop

```
#Program to calculate cost of gas on a trip
#Created by Sylvia McCoy, March 31, 2015
#Created in Python
#Declare Variables

Trip_Destination = 0
Number_Miles = 0
Current_MPG = 0.0
Gallon_Cost = 0.0
Total_Gallons = 0.0
Total_Cost = 0.0

#Loop to enter destinations

while True:
    Trip_Destination = input("Enter where you would like to travel:  ")
    Number_Miles = float(input("Enter how many miles to your destination:  "))
    Gallon_Cost = float(input("Enter how much a gallon of gas costs:  "))
    Current_MPG = float(Number_Miles / Gallon_Cost)
    print("Your trip to: " + Trip_Destination)
    print("Your total miles: " + Number_Miles)
    print("Your MPG:  " + Current_MPG)
```

Error in line 20 and 21...stated earlier as float, how do I get them to print? Have to do the work in Python. Thanks!

Comment: You are adding float to string which is not allowed.You need to convert the float value to string in the print statement like print("Your MPG:  " + str(Current_MPG))

Comment: Thank you! Now, if I want the loop to end, what would be the best code to end the loop?  I tried an "if" statement but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What does your if statement looks like ....

Comment: if Trip_Destination = ("No") :     print ("Thank-you, End of Program")   exit()

Comment: It should be like if Trip_Destination == "NO":break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `+` operator to combine a `string` with a `float`.

It can only be used to combine two of a single type (eg.2 strings, 2 floats, etc.)

With that said, to get your desired output, you can simplify ALL the conversions you need into one line, like so:

```
Trip_Destination = 0
Number_Miles = 0
Current_MPG = 0.0
Gallon_Cost = 0.0
Total_Gallons = 0.0
Total_Cost = 0.0

#Loop to enter destinations

while True:
    Trip_Destination = input("Enter where you would like to travel:  ")
    Number_Miles = input("Enter how many miles to your destination:  ")
    Gallon_Cost = input("Enter how much a gallon of gas costs:  ")
    Current_MPG = str(float(Number_Miles) / float(Gallon_Cost))
    print("Your trip to: " + Trip_Destination)
    print("Your total miles: " + Number_Miles)
    print("Your MPG:  " + Current_MPG)
```

Using the `input()` function by itself will let you get a value from the user (already in the form of a `string`). This way, you won't have to format/convert it later.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
while True:
    Trip_Destination = input("Enter where you would like to travel:  ")
    Number_Miles = float(input("Enter how many miles to your destination:  "))
    Gallon_Cost = float(input("Enter how much a gallon of gas costs:  "))
    Current_MPG = float(Number_Miles / Gallon_Cost)
    print("Your trip to: " + Trip_Destination)
    print("Your total miles:{}".format(Number_Miles))
    print("Your MPG:{}".format(Current_MPG))
```

**print("your string {}".format(x))**

its called string formatting

Answer (score 0):

#### Concatenation

You are trying to add a string and a float, in Python the two won't be automatically casted.

```
print("Your total miles: " + str(Number_Miles)) # same for miles per gallon
```

#### String Formats

Otherwise, you can also use string formatting in order to interpolate the desired variable.

```
print("Your total miles: {0}".format(Number_Miles)) # same miles per gallon
```